# Use Bash to test if PostgreSQL hstore extension is enabled

Tags: bash, postgresql

I need use a Bash test to check if the `hstore` extension is enabled in PostgreSQL. Advice appreciated.

#### Update

Thanks for the helpful answers. In spite of the haters this helped me write [this useful bash script that enables PostgreSQL hstore](http://ryanburnette.com/2015/01/enable-postgresql-hstore-with-bash.html).

Comment: Your link is no longer working

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can run a SQL statement that checks `pg_extension`, e.g.

```
select count(*) 
from pg_extension 
where extname = 'hstore';
```

And then check the return value of that (I don't use Linux/bash scripting so I'm not sure on how to do that in a shell script)

You probably need some command where you can use the output of the query. The following will simply output `0` or `1`

```
psql -t -A -c "select count(*) from pg_extension where extname = 'hstore'"
```

If you can access that result from within a shell script, then this should be enough

Comment: Add `| grep -q 1` after the command to rely on output code.
This can be specially useful if you want to test extension status in automated deployment script (puppet, chef, ...)

Answer (score 1):

Another aproach is to execute any hstore query and check if it worked:

```
psql template1 -c "select 'a=>1'::hstore ? 'a'"
echo $?
```